# How to change the entire theme's text color in Flutter?

Tags: text, colors, flutter

There is probably something obvious I'm missing. Is there *one* property that can change the color of all the text in a Flutter app?

The way I am doing it now is, in my MaterialApp:

```
theme: ThemeData(
    textTheme: Theme.of(context).textTheme.copyWith(
          body1:
              Theme.of(context).textTheme.body1.apply(color: Colors.pink),
          body2:
              Theme.of(context).textTheme.body2.apply(color: Colors.pink),
          display1:
              Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1.apply(color: Colors.pink),
          display2:
              Theme.of(context).textTheme.display2.apply(color: Colors.pink),
          ... // and so on
        ),
    ),
),
```

I also tried

```
textTheme: Theme.of(context).textTheme.apply(bodyColor: Colors.pink),
```

but this applies to Dropdown text, not regular text. Likewise, `displayColor` applies to the appBar text and a InputDecoration text, but not regular text. I don't seem to have any `decorationText` in my code so I'm not sure what that one is for.

I note there is a `textSelectionColor` property but that only applies for `TextField` widgets.

Answer (score 187, accepted):

I think [`TextTheme.apply`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/TextTheme/apply.html) is what you want. `bodyColor` will be applied to `headline`, `title`, `subhead`, `button`, `body1`, and `body2`. `displayColor` will be applied to `display1` through `display4`, and `caption`. If you specify both `bodyColor` and `displayColor` and use the same color value, that will effectively change text colors on all text styles.

Example:

```
final newTextTheme = Theme.of(context).textTheme.apply(
  bodyColor: Colors.pink,
  displayColor: Colors.pink,
);
```

Comment: Great! Did not realize that in combination, `bodyColor` and `displayColor` would cover all the cases.

Answer (score 70):

For the entire app, you can set `textTheme` property in the `Material` app widget.

```
MaterialApp(
  theme: ThemeData(
    textTheme: TextTheme(
      bodyText1: TextStyle(),
      bodyText2: TextStyle(),
    ).apply(
      bodyColor: Colors.orange, 
      displayColor: Colors.blue, 
    ),
  ),
)
```

Comment: how to set font size?

Comment: @JohnJoe In the `TextStyle`, you can use `fontSize`.

Comment: For this feature there are only "fontSizeFactor" and "fontSizeDelta" arguments, no "fontsize"

Comment: It's a shame that I have to write 15 lines, one for each of `displayLarge`, `headlineMedium`, `titleSmall` etc, but it works!

Answer (score 53):

To provide an alternative that seems to work without setting all the Text styles directly is to change the style of the `DefaultTextStyle` at the place in the Widget tree to take effect

```
return DefaultTextStyle(
  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.pink),
  child: _YOUR_WIDGETS_
)
```

Comment: This is a great answer when you want to force a `TextStyle` for a particular part of your app. None of the other answers worked in my case.

Answer (score 11):

Maybe a bit late... but you can use this:

```
ThemeData(
    primaryTextTheme: Typography(platform: TargetPlatform.iOS).white,
    textTheme: Typography(platform: TargetPlatform.iOS).white,
)
```

Comment: The tagetPlatform says iOS but it also works for Android.

Comment: This one worked for me pretty well. Remove the platform parameter and it'll work with android (because default value of platform parameter is android).

Comment: This worked for me on flutter web

Answer (score 7):

mine is working with this:

```
return MaterialApp(
  theme: ThemeData(
    textTheme: TextTheme(
      bodyText2: TextStyle(
        color: Colors.white,
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 1):

I found using copyWith() on the TextTheme works well, as you can just change specific properties like fontsize - leaving everthing else unchanged.

```
 textTheme: TextTheme().copyWith(
      bodyText2: TextStyle(
        fontSize: 30,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
      )
    ),
```

Comment: bodyText2 is deprecated

Answer (score 0):

Merge is used to change the color of text with the textTheme...

```
Text("Company",
style:Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText1?.merge(TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
)),
```

Answer (score 0):

'bodyText1', 'bodyText2' and the likes are deprecated and shouldn't be used. Use bodyMedium, bodySmall, bodyLarge etc instead.

This feature was deprecated after v3.1.0-0.0.pre:
[Documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextTheme-class.html)

An example to get you started quickly:

```dart
return MaterialApp(
  theme: ThemeData(
   textTheme: const TextTheme().copyWith(
    bodySmall: const TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
    bodyMedium: const TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
    bodyLarge: const TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
    labelSmall: const TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
    labelMedium: const TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
    labelLarge: const TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
    displaySmall: const TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
    displayMedium: const TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
    displayLarge: const TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
   ),
  ),
);
```