# How to override Theme for a part of application?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I have a small Flutter application with Theme configured like this:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  static final list = [
    {
      'name': 'test',
      'password': 'foobar'
    }
  ];
  final store = Store(appStateReducers, initialState: AppState(list));
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StoreProvider(
      store: store,
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.red,
          appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
            color: Color.fromRGBO(250, 136, 54, 1)
          ),
          textTheme: TextTheme(
            body1: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.red // text color is red for the whole applicatioin
            )
          )
        ),
        initialRoute: '/',
        routes: {
          '/': (context) => NoAccountPageDart(),
          'CreateAccount': (context) => CreateAccount(),
          'Home': (context) => Home()
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And on one of my screens I have a list of widgets where I want all text widgets to have another color. So I tried to use Theme widget folowing this [guide](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/design/themes#extending-the-parent-theme) for that like so:

```
//some code
child: Theme(
                          data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
                            textTheme: Theme.of(context).textTheme.copyWith(
                              body1: TextStyle(color: Colors.white) // this is the color I want to use
                            )
                          ),
                          child: Column(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Text(accounts[index]['name']), // this is supposed to be white. But it's still red.
                              Text(accounts[index]['password'],
                                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.green))
                            ],
                          ),
                        ));
//some code
```

But it didn't work. I have also tried to follow these [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49203740/how-to-change-the-entire-themes-text-color-in-flutter) on stackoverflow, and here how it looked in my code:

```
child: Theme(
                          data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
                            textTheme: Theme.of(context).textTheme.apply(
                              bodyColor: Colors.white // this is the color I want to use
                            )
                          ),
                          child: Column(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Text(accounts[index]['name']), // this is supposed to be white. But it's still red.
                              Text(accounts[index]['password'],
                                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.green))
                            ],
                          ),
                        ));
```

But this didn't work either. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you can use **Theme widget** as **parent of your Scaffold** in which you want to override global theme of app.

For Ex : Your Global theme is

theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        buttonColor: Colors.red
      ),

So, you have to use it with the syntax like,

```
color:Theme.of(context).buttonColor;
```

By, Adding Theme widget to specific screen like,

```
Theme(
      data: ThemeData(
            buttonColor: Colors.purple
      ),
      child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text("Demo"),
          ),
          body: Container(
                child: RaisedButton(
                      onPressed:(){},
                      child:Text("Save"),
                ),        
         ),
      )
)
```

For this particular screen your button color gets directly applied from your **nearest scaffold ThemeData** to the RaisedButton Color. you don't need to reference it using Theme.of(context).

This way you can create a global ThemeData and apply it to all the screens which needs some different theme configurations other than declared in MaterialApp ThemeData.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, Jay! So basically speaking, I can override my root Global theme by wrapping only my Scaffold widgets by Theme widget, right? 
What if I want to create a custom cart widget and override my theme only for all it's child widgets? Is it possible?

Comment: So, for all that child classes what you need to do is create a global or separate themeData. Then for all your child classes Add Theme as a parent widget to your scaffolds and provide global ThemeData. This way you can achieve it.

Comment: Is it okay to have multiple nested Scaffold widgets?